# Why do some paths show their center and some not?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

How come that some paths in AI always have a center (shown when the path is selected in any view that also shows anchor points) and some not?  If I draw a rectangle, there is a center, if I delete nodes and attach some custom path to it, the center gets retained.  But when I draw any free form with the pen tool, closed or open, there is no center.

How come this strange division between 'centered objects' and 'center-less objects' and is it possible convert between these two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can show or hide the center marker for any path from the Attributes panel:

[image]

I believe it is only rectangles and ellipses that show the center by default since that makes most sense... the center point of an irregular shape generally isn't of much use.